# github actions hides my jwt token retrieved from the backend

Tags: github, jwt, header, github-actions, github-secret

I have a CRON github action, which executes a python script.

First request goes well, the script gets jwt token from the backend.
Then when I am trying to do the second request, guarded by JwtGuard, the token is not attached in Authentication header.

I am logging the headers on backend and 'Authentication' header seems to be 'undefined'.

When I am trying to display jwtToken obtained from backend with Auth request, in Github Actions I can only see '***'.

What is the proper way to manage the token in github actions and attach it to the next requests properly?

Comment: GitHub Actions always hides secrets in the logs.  it may be that you're sending the token correctly, but it's just not being printed.

Comment: You are right. The problem was with my DNS configuration of domain where backend is deployed. There was nothing wrong with github at all.